# Android Studio not opening any project class file with proper format

Tags: android, android-studio, build, sdk, ide

I also try to **Invalidate Cache**, **Clean project**, **Rebuild Project**, Sync with file-system but every project have same problem so please solve my issue or help.

**Hear is my Android studio IDE**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Is your system or machine(your pc) in which you were working shut down while your studio was open while you were coding?

Comment: yes but how to solve this issue @Savin Sharma

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue few days back because my pc shut down while i was working. The problem is with your `Android Studio` not the code. If you check the same file in the project directory then you will find the file perfectly fine with your java code.

I tried all the possible solution which i found on the internet. Few of the solutions are which didn't work for me are -

1. Deleting the workspace.xml file
2. Deleting the .idea folder
3. Deleting gradle folder

**This is the solutions i found online but didn't work for me.**

What actually worked for me is my code was on github so i pushed the latest code on the github and then deleted the current working **project directory** i.e your **project folder** in your storage and again cloned a **new project** in another location.

Here the problem was with that particular project in your `Android Studio`. So after taking the backup of that project and deleting it and again creating the new project with the same code worked for me.